# UTF-8 Character map file

Tags: utf-8, locale, archlinux

I have a new installation of Arch -- within the past month -- and somehow recently my $LANG variable has gotten messed up. After some searching, trying to run locale-gen it appears somehow the UTF-8 file has disappeared.

```
[ryan@ARCHER /]$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8

[ryan@ARCHER /]$ ls usr/share/i18n/charmaps/

[ryan@ARCHER /]$ uname -a
Linux ARCHER 4.1.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to simply find somewhere to download or otherwise regenerate the UTF-8 encoding file.

Comment: There is no separate "UTF-8" file; the problem lies elsewhere. Not a programming question anyway; maybe try at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: As I said, there is supposed to be a `UTF-8.gz` file in the `usr/share/i18n/charmaps/` folder. But yeah I'll try looking over there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the file `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the line with the language and encoding options that you want to generate. In my file I have line 163 uncommented, which holds "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8".

After this you should be able to run locale-gen

This is as decribed on:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale

I apologize if I misunderstood the question and this is what you have already tried.

Comment: Yes I had run `locale-gen` with the appropriate lines uncommented from the `/etc/locale.gen` file. But I was missing the corresponding UTF-8 charmap file. I'm going to try again this weekend with the file pulled from another machine.